# Linux ext3 readdir and concurrent updates

Tags: linux, concurrency, readdir

we are receiving about 10000 messages per hour. We store them as individual files in hourly directories on an ext3 filesystem. The file name includes a sequence number. We use rsync to mirror these files every 20 seconds at another location (via a SAN, but that doesn't matter).

Sometimes an rsync run picks up files n-3, n-2, n-1, n+1, and then next rsync run continues with n, n+2, n+3, n+4 and so on.

Is it possible that when one process creates files in a certain sequence within a directory, that another process using `readdir()` sees the files appearing in a different sequence?

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Comment: rsync sorts file list lexicographically. What are file names? Also sorting algo may differ from version to version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your question can be restated as:

> If process A creates file `d/x` and
>   then creates file `d/y`, is it
>   possible for process B to peform a
>   concurrent `readdir()` on directory `d` and see
>   an entry `d/y`, but not see an entry
>   `d/x`?

The answer is Yes.  The ordering guarantees for `readdir` are very weak indeed.

If you want to enforce an ordering, you will need to explicitly `fsync()` a file descriptor for the directory `d` itself after creating each file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's weak indeed, and I'm still inclined to call it a bug. Do you have any pointers to Linux documentation or source code? Btw, we have now disabled the ext3 dir_index option, and whereas in the last month the issue occured a few times nearly every day, it has now not happened anymore for three days in a row.

Comment: I'm still wondering whether and how fsync could avoid this from happening.

Comment: @Wangnick: The relevant documentation is the POSIX spec for `readdir()`, which simply says *If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to opendir()  or rewinddir(), whether a subsequent call to readdir() returns an entry for that file is unspecified.* - note, no ordering guarantees.  If process A creates `d/x`, then calls `fsync(d)`, then creates `d/y`, then calls `fsync(d)` (etc) then you should get the externally visible ordering you desire.