# Iterating a DirectoryStream and changing contents of a directory at the same time

Tags: java, file-io, java-7, directory-structure

The documentation of DirectoryStream clearly states:

> The iterator is weakly consistent. It is thread safe but does not
>   freeze the directory while iterating, so it may (or may not) reflect
>   updates to the directory that occur after the DirectoryStream is
>   created.

On my machine, I executed a simple iteration over a directory in debug mode. Before the iteration completed, I broke execution, added a file to the directory being iterated and resumed. The iteration **did not see** the extra file.

My question: under what circumstance *will* the iteration reflect updates to the directory contents?
Unfortunately the formal documentation is very vague about it. To say the least.

Comment: I don't know, but the way I read it, it is nondeterministic, and may be dependant on the underlying OS/FS and or specific implementations. My best guess is that it will reflect updates if your directory is on an inode that is located later in the tree than the current one the iterator is pointing to.

How to provoke this behavior I do not know. I feel confident in saying it is not immediately possible (in a deterministic way) using pure Java.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is intentionally vague. The JVM has to run on a number of different kinds of machines: Windows and Unix-derivatives. Different file systems have different behaviors. You must (I repeat, MUST) design for the worst case if you want your program to work reliably on more than one computer.

The law of least surprise suggests that you should slurp up the entire DirectoryStream to get a snapshot (or very close to one), iterate over the snapshot, and then re-slurp the stream. You can then compare the different versions of the snapshots to determine changes to the underlying directory.

Comment: I completely agree with the conclusion, the question was out of academic interest.

Answer (score 2):

As `DirectoryStream` is an interface, and as this part of NIO.2 is intended to be pluggable, don't limit your consideration to the implementations that ship with the JDK for Linux and Windows. It would be quite possible to write a custom implementation with exactly that behaviour, or for a clustered or distributed implementation to have that behaviour as a side-effect.

The documentation is intentionally vague, and under POSIX it delegates to `readdir` which is [*also* intentionally vague](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir_r.html):

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to opendir() or rewinddir(), whether a subsequent call to readdir_r() returns an entry for that file is unspecified.

However, if you're after a concrete case where an implementation relied on that vagueness, then [Linux ext3 readdir and concurrent updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928459/linux-ext3-readdir-and-concurrent-updates) shows a case where `rsync`, on an `ext3` file system with high volume, appeared to see files appear in the directory outside the order they were created in.